# Can I shut off the email confirmation subscription from MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp, squarespace

I have a problem with the link with MailChimp. The problem is that MailChimp is sending an email to confirm subscription every time somebody is filling any kind of form. But, I don't want MailChimp to do that, because my prospects are not subscribing for newsletter (I mean, not each time they are filling a form). So, I'm afraid my prospects will run away when they will see that strange email in there inbox.

Is there a way to shut this email off ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A confirmation is good to know that users exist or you want be sending it to people whose email addresses were bought but are no longer using them. Also buying an email list is not recommended (not saying you are), it will affect the deliverability of the campaign and not to mention complaints can cause black listing. Now having said that try and see if you can change the optin status from double to single (even if they give the option). I know dotmailer does/used to give an to change a user from double option to single optin.

Comment: Thanks. I already found a way to bypass the email confirmation.

Comment: how did you bypass it?

Comment: I used their api and added a status `subscribed`.